# Why does wingwalking use only biplanes?

Tags: aerobatics, biplane

Wingwalking is an aerobatic discipline with shows such as [this](https://twitter.com/airsports_fai/status/672381676446613504) [one](https://fai.org/news/wing-walking-girls-steal-hearts-dubai).
The definition of wingwalking from Wikipedia gives no other alternative than using biplanes:

> Wing walking is the act of moving along the wings of a biplane during flight [...]

(source: [Wikipedia, as of 26 February 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wing_walking&oldid=942804092))

When searching for images on the web, I can only find [biplanes](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=wingwalking), mainly [stearman](https://www.airliners.net/search?aircraftBasicType=12351&keywords=wingwalker) but also [other biplanes](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Gene-Soucy/Grumman-G-164A-Show-Cat/63394).

For me, it seems that any aircraft with high wings or parasol wings can do the job, so why do they only use biplanes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw a monoplane wing walk at Oshkosh when I was a kid, but it is rare.

Comment: @GdD why is it so rare? I cannot find any occurrence in the last three decades.

Comment: I don't know, but I suspect a high wing keeps the walker out of the rudder's airflow.

Comment: Perhaps walk on biplan is more easy than on monoplane!

Answer (score 27):

It doesn't only use biplanes, searching "wingwalking monoplane" provides these examples, of some low wing monoplane and high wing monoplane.
Whatever the aircraft, it has to be able to fly slowly.

[image]
([source](https://www.aerotime.aero/aviation-blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/http-2F2Fa.amz_.mshcdn.com2Fwp-content2Fuploads2F20152F092Fwingwalkers-1.jpg)) (not 100% about this one but it looks like one Klemm aircraft)

[image]
([source](http://www.natureandtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/wing-walker-300x173.jpg))
(Here one quite rare danish SAI KZ III equipped with a hatch behind the wing, allowing acrobat Palle Johnson to get out.)

[image: jaromir wagner]
([source](https://fly.historicwings.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/HighFlight-JaromirWagner3.jpg))
(Jaromir Wagner, Czech wingwalker holding speed record wingwalking at 270km/h here on a Britten-Norman Islander aircraft)

Comment: last picture looks like a special effect from a movie - the lighting is entirely too keyed imo

Comment: @NKCampbell It is - from [Flying Down to Rio (1933)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Down_to_Rio).  The special effects were done by Linwood Dunn :  [Linwood Dunn’s special effects used back projection and process photography in the famous final aviation dance sequence.](http://jimhanson.org/flyingdowntoriointro.html)

Comment: @NKCampbell nice find, I just found another high wing wing walker, which is real, and will replace this one, thanks

Answer (score 19):

3 reasons:

1. The really obvious one; biplanes had the interplane structural network to hang on to when doing the wing walking.  It's a heck of a lot safer for the wing walker.  Even today, most of the wing walker acts use Stearman or Waco biplanes.
2. They generally have lower wing loadings than comparable monoplanes so could fly slower.
3. They were readily available as WWI surplus in the 20s when the whole Air Circus business was getting underway.  Equivalent monoplanes would be new production and much more expensive to acquire.

So while there are/were monoplane wing walker acts, they weren't true "wing walkers". The original wing walkers walked out from the fuselage to the wing tip, and the usual trick on the Jenny was to get down and hang from the wing tip protector hoop that extends down below the interplane struts.  It was only possible on a biplane because there was structure and wires to hang on to.

The monoplane acts are great stunt acts, but they aren't true wing walking acts because no, you know, ***walking along the wing***, goes on.  They have a brace to let someone stand up above the fuselage, but you won't see any of them walking out along the wing to the tip without any kind of aids, as you do on a biplane.

Comment: The interplane bracing is the wrong side of the wing, beneath their feet where they can't reach it.

Comment: @Guy Inchbald Look at any wing walker act on a Jenny or such from the 20s.  They are moving between the wings hanging on to the rigging, not along the top one.

Comment: Yeah, any realistic wing-walking requires some sort of rigging to hold onto, at least intermittently.  In the pictures of monoplane walkers that rigging has been added specifically to enable the walking.

Comment: One more point for biplanes: there are many more biplanes with the combination of open cockpits (necessary for the acrobat to get into and out of a seat for takeoff and landing), aerobatic capability, *and* slow flight than there are monoplanes.  Additionally, today, the *look* of the act is heavily tied to biplanes.

Comment: @JohnK. True that a minority do that (in fact the very first to wing-walk did, back in 1913), but it is hardly "the really obvious one" for the majority of wing-walking.

Comment: Plenty of monoplanes (albeit mostly early ones) also have bracing struts and wires on top of the wings.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: So a door wouldn't work?

Comment: It's an obvious one when it comes to the advantage of using a biplane.  Try walking out to tip of the wing of a monoplane even one with bracing wires going half way out, without special modifications.  A Jenny didn't and only cost a couple hundred bucks.

Comment: @sean Getting from a side door to the top of the wing is difficult and hazardous -- especially since many wing walkers, to add spice to the act, don't (or claim not to) wear a parachute (and it's killed more than a few -- part of the risk of the job).

Answer (score 2):

I'd offer that it's due to the speed of the plane. I have seen it done with mono-wing planes as well, but it's rare, as others have also mentioned. The rationale for biplanes is likely twofold:

1. There's a nostalgia element to be considered, now that the style of plane is out of fashion, and has been for some time.
2. Two wings means more aerodynamic lift. The additional weight in the plane or just the stress on the plane itself combined with lower airspeed means that the plane needs all the help it can get to remain airborne, especially when stunts are involved.

Comment: "Two wings means more aeronautical lift."  Errr, what?

Comment: @MikeBrockington: Presumably he meant "more _aerodynamic_ lift".  Which is true - a biplane's greater total wing area _does_ provide more lift than that of a monoplane of equal wingspan, chord length, and wing shape (although, due to interference between the airflow around the two wings, nowhere near the twice-as-much that one would intuitively expect).

Comment: thanks @Sean, yes. that's what I meant. I just jump into different SE forums from time to time to learn about things I'm not normally into.

Comment: @Sean  But what advantage to wing-walking does a shorter wingspan mean? Due to the intimate relationship with drag, no plane is going to have significantly more overall lift than it needs - they are designed for a specific payload, regardless of one wing or two.